# Vb.net how to find value on column on datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I'm stuck at finding

My table  is:

```
Passenger | Destination  | Status

23        |  Mars        | PWD
```

I can find the value of PWD on 3rd column but I can't multiply it on column 1 where column 3 has value of PWD.

Here is my code for finding the PWD value:

```
For a As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If (DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(2).Value IsNot DBNull.Value Or Trim(DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(2).Value <> Nothing) AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(2).Value = "PWD") Then
        PWD = PWD + 1
    End If
Next
Dim pwdcount = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows _
                  Where row.Cells("Status").Value = "PWD" And row.Cells("Status").Value IsNot DBNull.Value _
                  Select row.Cells("Status").Value).Count()
label1.text = "The number of PWD is : " & pwdcount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be trying to find a LINQ solution, which is not what I'm suggesting below.  But I believe this will meet your requirement...

```
    Dim pwdcount As Integer

    For Each oRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim oPassengerCell As DataGridViewCell = oRow.Cells("Passenger")
        Dim oStatusCell As DataGridViewCell = oRow.Cells("Status")

        If IsNumeric(oPassengerCell.Value) AndAlso oStatusCell.Value = "PWD" Then
            pwdcount += oPassengerCell.Value
        End If
    Next

    Label1.Text = "The number of PWD is : " & pwdcount
```

Comment: value alwys gets +1

Comment: total should be 30 but it says 33 coz every column got +1 value